# Can not login after logout facebook for release apk Android

Tags: android, facebook, hash, authentication, key

I create an Android apps with Facebook Login. For debug apps i have no problem, login successfully, but after i create apk for release my apps generate different Key Hash (i'm using openssl to generate it) , for first login it was success, but after logout it cant login again with message "invalid key hash", which is it the different Key Hash what i mean before.

I copied the key hash into my facebook apps setting, its still invalid, but after i remove the apps from setting in Facebook Web, and login again it was success, but after logout  and login again its come back to invalid key. I have no clue with this problem, i was search it anywhere and cant solve it. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paste your SHA-1 from the signed app in this online converter -  http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php , and the resulted output add to the hash you already added (the debug) to your Facebook developer page, after that there shouldn't be problems.

Comment: Wow.. you save my life, thank you so much.. Idont know why the result is same if i type it manually, but the key from your converter can accepted by facebook. Can you explain to me?

Comment: It is hard to say what exactly was your problem without seeing exactly what you have done, but in general this is the most straightforward way how to do it, big thanks to the author of the webpage, it really helped me when i found it some time ago.

Comment: ok, maybe i miss 1 character which it look like same. Anyway thank you @attels